# Rails 3.2.1 asset precompile error when using !important in .css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

when I do a rake assets:precompile on my rails app it fails if I have the config

```
config.assets.compress = true
```

The block that is causing the error is

```
.banner-row {
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0px; !important
padding: 0px; !important    
}
```

The error I get is

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "margine: 0px; ":expected "}", was !important"
```

The precompile task passes with compress = false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.banner-row {
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0px !important; 
padding: 0px !important;
}
```